# Why are alkenes considered nonpolar?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology, hydrocarbons, polarity

Alkenes have C–C sigma bonds, C=C pi bonds, and also C–H sigma bonds.

I know that C–C and C=C bonds will not give any polarity, but what about the C–H bond?

I think it should give some polarity because C is slightly more electronegative than H, so the electrons in the C–H bond will be slightly polarised towards C.

But alkenes are typically referred to as non-polar. Why?

Comment: It depends on the resultant of the electrical dipole moments, which anyways aren't so important. Of course you might find something if you look for small things.

Comment: "Alkene" is not a compound. You are overgeneralising. Look at specific examples, I recommend you start with the two simplest, ethylene and propylene.

Comment: "Non-polar" in chemistry means _"not particularly polar"_, rather than _"not polar at all"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. On the grand scale of things, the polarity of a $\ce{C-H}$ bond is very low. The electronegativity difference is less than $0.5$ which is generally the cutoff of a mostly unpolar bond.
2. Typically when looking at an alkene at large, the various (small) polarities of the different $\ce{C-H}$ bonds cancel each other out or come very close to doing so. In ethene, they cancel out completely for symmetry reasons. In propene, they should likewise cancel out to almost zero total dipole moment. The larger your alkene gets, the less exact this cancelling will be but the general trend remains the same.

Answer (score 5):

A compound or a molecule being polar or non-polar is rather a fuzzy term.

Being non-polar does not mean no polarity of chemical bonds.

It means this polarity is low enough for atoms of such a molecule not to  interact with other molecules by relatively strong inter-molecular interactions. These include strong dipole-dipole interactions, hydrogen bonds or donor-acceptor bonds.